# LinearLayout.setRotation(180f) gives different coordinate by getLocationOnScreen : Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-coordinatorlayout, android-screen

i have linear layout xml like,

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_white_petroling"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/View06"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/View01"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_back_1_2"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/red_dot" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <View
                                  android:id="@+id/iv_white_petroling_collider"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="73dp"
                            android:background="#99212121"
                            android:visibility="visible" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_white_petroling"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ch_right1" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_front_1_2"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/red_dot" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

after some time i rotate this layout programmatically by,

**ll_white_petroling.setRotation(180f);**

now when i trying to check rect by,

```
int[] v2_coords = new int[2];
ll_white_petroling.getLocationOnScreen(v2_coords);
```

it gives wrong coordinates !